# Can i get the logged in user roles in sequence mediator?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I could not find any documentation to retrieve user roles in a sequence mediator using XML or Java.

I did some guessing like this but it didn't work

`<property name="user" expression="get-property('api.ut.roles')"/>`

Also is it possible to read api scopes.

Comment: Can you explain more about the requirement that you are trying to achieve? Can you elaborate more on the use case with few samples?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [backend JWT](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/) and use it to get the roles of the user.